# Is there an incompressible vector field $\mathbf{F}$ with $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = (y^2, z^2, x^2)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I want to find an incompressible vector field $\mathbf{F}$ such that $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = (y^2,z^2,x^2)$.

After some attempts to find such $\mathbf{F}$, I think the vector field $\mathbf{F}$ with given conditions may not exist. However even for this side, I do not have an idea to proceed. Since $\mathbf{F}$ is incompressible we have $\mathbf{F} = \nabla \times \mathbf{G}$ for some $\mathbf{G}$, which leads to $\nabla \times(\nabla \times \mathbf{G}) = (y^2,z^2,x^2)$. However there is no additional property that I know about double curl to prove nonexistence of such $\mathbf{F}$.

Thanks in advance for any form of help, hint, or solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, such  incompressible vector field $\mathbf{F}$ exists.  Consider
$$\mathbf{G}=(-y^4/12,-z^4/12,-x^4/12)$$
then
$$\mathbf{F}=\nabla \times \mathbf{G}=(z^3/3,x^3/3,y^3/3)$$
and finally
$$\nabla\times \mathbf{F}= (y^2,z^2,x^2).$$
More generally, from the definition of [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Usage) in cartesian coordinates,
$$\begin{align}
\nabla \times(\nabla \times (f(y),g(z),h(x)))&=
\nabla \times (-g'(z),-h'(x),-f'(y))\\
&=-(f''(y),g''(z),h''(x)).\end{align}$$

Comment: How to prove the general expression $\nabla \times(\nabla \times (f(y),g(z),h(x)))=
-(f''(y),g''(z),h''(x)).$

Comment: @user1942348 Just apply the basic definition of curl in cartesian coordinates two times. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Is it possible to find a solution using the approach you suggested https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711452/find-an-irrotational-function-fx-and-a-solenoidal-function-gx-such-that/4712578#4712578

Comment: No, in the other problem the components are not functions of just one variable each. A more general approach is needed.

Comment: Could you please help for the more general approach that you have mentioned

Comment: You have already a good answer. What is wrong with that? Please post your comments below the other question.

Comment: RobertZ I have mentioned

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 0
$$
for incompressible field. Thus
$$
\partial_x F_x + \partial_y F_y + \partial_z F_z= 0
$$
we have from the curl
$$
\left(\partial_y F_z - \partial_zF_y\right)\mathbf{e_x} - \left(\partial_x F_z - \partial_zF_x\right)\mathbf{e_y} + \left(\partial_x F_y - \partial_yF_x\right)\mathbf{e_z}  
$$
or
$$
\partial_x F_y - \partial_yF_x = x^2\\
\partial_y F_z - \partial_zF_y = y^2\\
\partial_z F_x - \partial_x F_z  = z^2
$$

we know from the incompressible requirement that $F_x = kx$ or $F_x =g(y,z)$ e.g. independent of $x$ and by symmetry the same for all other components.

Comment: How to find F from $\partial_x F_y - \partial_yF_x = x^2\\
\partial_y F_z - \partial_zF_y = y^2\\
\partial_z F_x - \partial_x F_z  = z^2
$

Comment: That came from the curl $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}$ you defined and equating the components.

Answer (score 2):

There's an identity .

$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec{G})=\nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec{G})-\nabla ^2\vec{G}=(y^2,z^2,x^2)$.

To simply things, let's assume $\nabla \cdot \vec{G}=0$.

$-\nabla^2 G_x=\frac{-\partial^2 G_x}{\partial y ^2}=y^2\implies G_x=\frac{-y^4}{12}$. By symmetry you can reproduce Robert Z's answer.

A bit more difficult, you can find solutions where $\nabla \cdot \vec{G} \ne 0 $.

Comment: $\frac{-\partial^2 G_x}{\partial y ^2}=y^2$ does not only imply $G_x=\frac{-y^4}{12}$, considering constant of integration, there would be other terms, Is is a particular solution?

Comment: Figure we're only really worried about the derivatives of $\vec{G}$ in the end so, while you're right, the constants disappear.