# Find an irrotational function $F(x)$ and a solenoidal function $G(x)$ such that $H = F + G$.

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator, curl

Let $H(x) = x^2y\,\mathbf{i} + y^2z\,\mathbf{j} + z^2x\,\mathbf{k}\,$. Find an irrotational function $F(x)$ and a solenoidal
function $G(x)$ such that $H = F + G$.

Sol. As $F(x)$ is irrotational function then $\operatorname{curl} F(x)=0$ and $G(x)$ is solenoidal then $\operatorname{div} G(x)=0\,$

How to use the above two relations to find $F$ and $G\,?$

We have  $$\operatorname{div}\operatorname{curl} \,H(x)=0\,.$$

Using it, $0=\operatorname{div}\operatorname{curl}H = \operatorname{div}\operatorname{curl}F + \operatorname{div}\operatorname{curl}G$, but we get an identity ($0=0+0$ type).

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Not grad, but div (or rot). What have you tried?

Comment: @TedShifrin I am confused, how to start? I started with $div \,curl \,H(x)=0$, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is interesting because $H$ is not bounded on $\mathbb R^3$
and the usual integral formulas from the [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) cannot be applied.

A [solenoidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoidal_vector_field) field $G$ is not one that has grad$\,G=0$ as you wrote but div$\,G=0\,.$ From
$$
\operatorname{div}H=2(xy+yz+zx)\,,\quad\operatorname{curl}H=-\left(\begin{smallmatrix}y^2\\z^2\\x^2\end{smallmatrix}\right)
$$
it follows that you are looking for fields $G$ and $F$ that have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{div}F&=2(xy+yz+zx)\,,\quad \operatorname{curl}G=-\left(\begin{smallmatrix}y^2\\z^2\\x^2\end{smallmatrix}\right)\,.
\end{align}
Since $\operatorname{curl}F=0$ it is of the form $F=\operatorname{grad}\Phi$
with some scalar function $\Phi\,.$ What you have to solve now is the Poisson equation
\begin{align}
\operatorname{div\,grad}\Phi=\Delta\Phi&=2(xy+yz+zx)\,.
\end{align}
Once this is done it follows that $G:=H-\operatorname{grad}\Phi$ is divergence free.

A simpler approach is the following:

Using the anti-curl formula from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4651493/949989) yields a field $G'$
\begin{align}
G'&:=\left[-\int_0^1t\left(\begin{smallmatrix}(ty)^2\\(tz)^2\\(tx)^2 \end{smallmatrix}\right)\,dt\right]\times\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{smallmatrix}\right)=-\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}y^2\\z^2\\x^2\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=-\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}z^3-x^2y\\x^3-y^2z\\y^3-z^2x\end{pmatrix}\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}z^3\\x^3\\y^3\end{pmatrix}+\frac{1}{4}H
\end{align}
which has the desired $\operatorname{curl}G'=-\left(\begin{smallmatrix}y^2\\z^2\\x^2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ but is not divergence free: ($\operatorname{div}G'=(xy+yz+zx)/2$).

Still, the ansatz
$$
F'=H-G'=\frac{3}{4}H+\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}z^3\\x^3\\y^3\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}z^3+3x^2y\\x^3+3y^2z\\y^3+3z^2x\end{pmatrix}
$$
leads to a field $F'$ that has
$$
\operatorname{div}F'=\frac{3}{2}(xy+yz+zx)\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\boxed{\quad
F:=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}z^3+3x^2y\\x^3+3y^2z\\y^3+3z^2x\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}z^3\\x^3\\y^3\end{pmatrix}+H\quad}
$$
has the desired divergence $\operatorname{div}F=2(xy+yz+zx)\,.$
It can be checked that $F$ is rotation free.
Finally, $G$ is
$$\boxed{\quad
G=H-F=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}z^3\\x^3\\y^3\end{pmatrix}\quad}
$$
which is obviously divergence-free.

The function $\Phi$ whose gradient is $F$ is

> $$\Phi(x,y,z)=\frac{x^3y+y^3z+z^3x}{3}\,.$$

Comment: It is perfect. Is it possible to solve without using anti-curl formula?

Comment: @user1942348 A don't see any easier shortcut...

Comment: @user1942348 . After seeing this [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709372/is-there-an-incompressible-vector-field-mathbff-with-nabla-times-mathbf/4709470#4709470) today I thought that it is not that difficult to see that the final $$G=\frac{1}{3}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}z^3\\x^3\\y^3\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$ has the curl we wanted it to have.